# Do we need to get certified from UL if we have certified from IEC to sell a electric/electronic product in the US market?

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, charger

A inverter/charger has EN-IEC 60335-1, EN-IEC 60335-2-29, IEC 62109-1 but is not certified by UL standard.

So isn't the UL mandatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generaly speaking, UL is not mandatory (as isn't TÜV for instance) but it may be requested by certain markets specificaly if there are national deviations in some states that were not specifically covered by the mentioned standards. You may consider the CB scheme for your product(s) as an additional peace of mind. UL may be seen however as an advantage if your big clients demanded it as some will refuse products if there is no UL or CSA certificate on request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, So are the IEC standards mandatory for the products to be sold in US then?

Comment: There is a minimum set of standards that are applicable to your product. I'm not entirely familiar with the standards you mention so I advise you to check with a competent test laboratory in your region that would know exactly the requirements for your product.

Comment: Does both UL and IEC comes under CB scheme ?

Comment: No, this will have to be worked out with the laboratory in your region....